# Solve the following problem graphically

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, telescopic-series

I have a small question here ... If the problem has constrain (=) like this $...4x+3y=1$. how to do it in the graph to get the region ... Overlooking the original point or not?

Comment: $4x + 3y = 1$ represents a line

Comment: That I mean , I graph it only and not care about it when determine the region ?

Comment: @user619263 what region are you referring to ?

Comment: Bounded region ..It's called (M) sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 4X + 3Y = 1 is one of your constraints, and you are solving the problem graphically, it will mean that your solution region/Bounded region will be narrowed down to just points on the line (and not above/below it, like you would see with an inequality).